# Tomcat don't load maven provided dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, module, dependencies

have eclipse, tomcat, maven and project with modules

```
the parent is pom
module 1 is jar (it's dependency for other modules)
module 2-7 - war
```

in parent pom have some dependencies with scope `provided`

when i build WARs - get lightweight files without deps
but if i run tomcat server in eclipse with modules 2-7 - tomcat don't load maven dependencies

i don't understand,what i should wrote in parent pom for lightweight WARs and load jars in debug together
help,please

**UPDATE**

solve with 2 profiles and 1 parameter as `scope` for all deps

Answer (score 0):

If you mark a dependency as `provided`, you say that the container (Tomcat in your case) will provide it.

Maven will not do that for you, but you need to configure it yourself in Tomcat.

Comment: every module 2-7 in Deployment Assembly contains Maven Dependency,but they don't loads

Comment: So did you put the dependencies into Tomcat?

Comment: should i do it with my hands with every dep?

Comment: Maven will not do it for you. If Tomcat does not have a mechanism for it, you need to do it by hand.

Comment: deployment assembly is this mechanism in eclipse isn't it?

Comment: I don't know. I just wanted to tell you that marking something as `provided` will _not_ put it in Tomcat.

Comment: i know it,but how i can make for dev on local change scope to `compile`,for example,and for build change on `provided`,cuz Deployment Assembly not works in this case